Unloading Snowflake table data from an EMPTY table into S3 in Parquet format
I am running copy jobs from snowflake tables to S3, and few of the tables are empty. Is there a way to generate an empty parquet file for these tables?
Below is the COPY command:
COPY INTO @athena_s3_stage_accounts
FROM (select * from athena_test_db.s3_connect_demo.accounts)
FILE_FORMAT = s3_parquet_file_format
OVERWRITE=TRUE;

Below is the definition of the file format:
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT s3_parquet_file_format
TYPE = PARQUET
COMPRESSION = SNAPPY;

Currently for the tables having data, the parquet file is generated correctly. But there is No file  generated for tables having empty data. I am expecting at least the column data to be present in the parquet file.

can you include the definition of your file_format?

Added the file format definition in the description

This is the documented, expected behaviour. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location#usage-notes. "If the source table contains 0 rows, then the COPY operation does not unload a data file"

This helps. Thank you Nick and Mike!
